# The transcendence degree  of the algebras  of invariants

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, classical-invariant-theory

Let  $V_n,V_m$ be  the vector $\mathbb{C}$-spaces of   the binary forms of degrees $n,m$  considered as usual $SL_2$-modules. Let $I_{n,m}=\mathbb{C}[V_n \oplus V_m]^{SL_2}$ and $C_{n,m}=\mathbb{C}[V_n \oplus V_m \oplus \mathbb{C}^2]^{SL_2}$ be the corresponding algebras of joint  invariants and covariants. The transcendence degree of $I_{n,m}$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is $n+m-1.$

**Questions:**

1. What is the transcendence degree of $C_{n,m}$ over  the subalgebra  $I_{n,m}$?
2. What is the transcendence degree of $C_{n,m}$ over  the quotient field  of the subalgebra  $I_{n,m}$?

Comment: I think you meant to write that the transcendence degree of $I_{n,m}$ (not $C_{n,m}$) over $\mathbb{C}$ is $m{+}n{-}1$.   Isn't it true that the transcendence degree of $C_{n,m}$ over $I_{n,m}$ is $2$?

Comment: @Robert Thanks, corrected. Please, any reference to the result that $trdegC_{n,m}$ over $I_{n,m}$ is 2. What about the second question?